# AudioManager MODE_IN_CALL interferences

Tags: android, media-player, android-audiomanager

I'm using AudioManager to play a sound through earpiece just before a call is placed so I use AudioManager setMode(MODE_IN_CALL).

I'm not having any problems except in Galaxy S3 where after playing the music correctly, ringtone sounds very distorted and very noisy. I've read setMode documentation:

```
The audio mode encompasses audio routing AND the behavior of the telephony 
layer. Therefore this method should only be used by applications that replace
the platform-wide management of audio settings or the main telephony application.
In particular, the MODE_IN_CALL mode should only be used by the telephony
application when it places a phone call, as it will cause signals from the 
radio layer to feed the platform mixer.
```

So I suspect there may be signals from radio layer feeding platform mixer.

So the code I'm using is like this:

```
am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
speakerWasOn = am.isSpeakerphoneOn();
speakerPrevMode = am.getMode();
bthA2dpWasOn = am.isBluetoothA2dpOn();
bthScoWasOn = am.isBluetoothScoOn();

if (BluetoothBR.bthOn && BluetoothBR.conectarBluetooth()) {
  am.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
  am.setBluetoothA2dpOn(true);
  am.setBluetoothScoOn(true);

} else {
  am.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
  am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
}
```

Then I use MediaPlayer to play the .mp3 file in a separated thread:

```
private OnPreparedListener opl = new OnPreparedListener() {
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    try {
      mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
      mp.start();

    } catch (Throwable e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      mp.release();
    }
  }
};

private OnCompletionListener ocl = new OnCompletionListener() {
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    stop();
  }
};

public void run() {
  synchronized (mp) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
      fis = new FileInputStream(getMp3FilePath());

      mp.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
      mp.setOnPreparedListener(opl);
      mp.setOnCompletionListener(ocl);
      mp.prepare();
      fis.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      mp.release();
      if (fis != null) {
        try {
          fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
          e1.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

public void stop() {
  if (mp != null) {
    try {
      mp.stop();
      mp.release();
      mp.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);
      mp.reset();

    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
  }

  if (BluetoothBR.bthOn) {
    BluetoothBR.desconectarBluetooth();
  }
}
```

And when music is done I call:

```
am.setSpeakerphoneOn(speakerWasOn);
am.setMode(speakerPrevMode);
am.setBluetoothA2dpOn(bthA2dpWasOn);
am.setBluetoothScoOn(bthScoWasOn);
```

This is only happening on Samsung Galaxy S3 (afaik) and has been tested in S2, Huawei, SonyEricsson, and others and works correctly.

Any Ideas?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I have discovered that all works fine if the thread waits 5 seconds when the music finishes and after setting AudioManager to original state.

```
am.setSpeakerphoneOn(speakerWasOn);
am.setMode(speakerPrevMode);
am.setBluetoothA2dpOn(bthA2dpWasOn);
am.setBluetoothScoOn(bthScoWasOn);

long ctime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (System.currentTimeMillis() - ctime < 5000);
```

Comment: STREAM_VOICE_CALL is NOT a mode, it's value is 0 so you are actually setting the mode to MODE_NORMAL which is also 0.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When i commented out this line

```
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```

All worked fine for me.